# iCarousel with per image reflection

Tags: ios, icarousel

How can I add a reflection to card flow for each image where the reflection is made from the image?

OR

How can I add common reflection for images with various aspect ration.

---

I can understand the reflection is taken from background image from reusable view but I need to make some setup for each item.

I found some other similar questions but I can't see solution for me there.

Answer (score 0):

There is an example on the library's [github](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel) which is also referred to in the FAQ at the bottom.

> Q. I want my carousel items to have a real reflection, but the reflection in the examples is just drawn on. How can I render reflections dynamically?
>
> A. iCarousel doesn't have built-in reflection support, but you can use some additional libraries to do this. Check out the *Dynamic View Reflections* and  *Dynamic Image Effects* examples.